# Creating multiple QtGui.QWidget dynamically

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

What i want to do:

- list of names which changes over time
- an infinite loop ("while True:") that creates a QtGui.QWidget for each name in the list - when a new name pops up in the list --> create a new QtGui.QWidget

What i have so far:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    import sys

    try:
        _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
    except AttributeError:
        def _fromUtf8(s):
            return s

    try:
        _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
    except AttributeError:
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

    class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, player_name):
            self.player_name = player_name
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
            self.setupUi(self)

        def setupUi(self, Form):
        ...


    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form('player_1')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now the code above works fine for creating the widget for 'player_1'. I can also create more than one Ui_Form like this without any issue.

For example:

```
    app = HUD.QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex_1 = HUD.Ui_Form('player_1')
    ex_2 = HUD.Ui_Form('player_2')
    ex_1.show()
    ex_2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My question now: Is there a way to create the widgets dynamically? For example in a for loop with a list:

```
    for player in player_list:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = Ui_Form('player')
        ex.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

"I know that the code above is not correct but it shows the idea."

Is that simply not possible due to the ".exec_()" and the fact that it is blocking till the app is closed?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the suggestion of  Robert Jacobs i tried using separate threads for each player and it works.

Here my code:

```
from subprocess import call
from threading import Thread
import time, os

class myClassA(Thread):
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.player_name = player_name
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        call(["python","Widget.py",self.player_name])

test_list = ['player_1','player_2']

for i in test_list:
    myClassA(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

So basically what i am doing is calling my first script "widget.py" for each player in a separate thread from my 2nd script.

Without the "time.sleep(1)" at the end only the first of the two windows opens, any idea why?

Is there way to check if a window with the same title (the title of the window = player_name) already exists?

Comment: You could try putting each player in a separate thread. The main thread could then join all the threads at the end.

Comment: @RobertJacobs: you meant it in that way? (update of my first post)